# What's the definition of absorption cross section?

Tags: scattering, scattering-cross-section

I'm now studying quantum scattering theory and I'm confused as to what the word "absorption cross-section" means.
My textbook writes it as
$$
\sigma_\mathrm{abs}=\sigma_\mathrm{total} - \sigma_\mathrm{el}
$$
I can't understand why this equation is valid.
Can anyway explain what this means, or recommend a useful textbook to understand scattering theory?

Comment: What do those two terms on the right hand side mean?

Comment: From the context of the textbook,$\sigma_{total}$means total cross-section, and $\sigma_{el}$means elastic cross-section.

Comment: OK, and what does elastic cross section mean?

Comment: elastic cross-section describes the area through which all the ﬂux passes which is scattered at all.

Comment: OK, so isn't this equation saying that the total cross section is the sum of the cross sections for scattering or absorption?

Comment: Maybe I understand it. So, if the scattering event is totally classical, will the absorption cross-section be $0$?